# Update a RecyclerView item wth no dataChange, only the UI element

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an event-timeline and want to update the timeline markers with an active, in_active and pre_active marker. The problem is I have to "restart" the fragment to see the marker changes. Is there any possibilities to see the changes live?

The events has an time stamp and an duration. If the current event is active i want to show the active_marker and if the event is finished the in_active marker and the future events get an future_marker.

**The Adapter:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TimeLineViewHolder holder, int position) {
    TimeLineData timeLineData = feedList.get(position);

    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar endDate = (Calendar) timeLineData.getRealTime().clone();
    endDate.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);   // Event Duration 

    if (currentDate.after(endDate)) {
        holder.timelineView.setMarker(holder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_marker_inactive));
    }
    if (currentDate.after(timeLineData.getRealTime()) && currentDate.before(endDate)) {
        holder.timelineView.setMarker(holder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_marker_active));
    }
    if (currentDate.before(timeLineData.getRealTime())) {
        holder.timelineView.setMarker(holder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_marker_future));
    }

    holder.title.setText(timeLineData.getStartup1() + " VS " + timeLineData.getStartup2());
    holder.time.setText(timeLineData.getTime()); 
}
```

timeLineData.getTime is the formatted Time String.

timeLineData.getRealTime is the Calender Object.

**The Fragment:**

```
public class TimeLineFragment extends Fragment {
private List<TimeLineData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View timeLineView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timeLine_recycler, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = timeLineView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    setUpEntries(recyclerView);
    return timeLineView;
}
private void setUpEntries(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
     TimeLineData model1 = new TimeLineData();
     ...
     model1.setTime(2019, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 12, 10, 0);
```

`setTime()` get the data like (year,month,day,hour,minute)

Comment: Recyclerview `onBindViewHolder` updates the items view every time that it comes up in the screen (while scrollong) maybe making your changes in this method can solve your problem.

Comment: This will help you: https://github.com/RomainPiel/TextChronometer

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean my Marker change are in the `onBindViewHolder` method but this didn't work @H.sanati

Comment: I think this isn't a working solution for my problem  @ישואוהבאותך